# lmer p values used to create the stars listed by screenreg

Tags: r, lme4

This may be an obvious question that I have yet to be able to find an answer for (R newbie), but when generating a mixed effects model using the `lmer` function then displaying the results using:

```
screenreg(list(model4re), single.row = TRUE)
```

we get a list of the beta estimates, standard error and the significance level in the form of stars.

What test is used to determine these p-values to label the stars (Important as I recognize that there is some contention around how appropriately  determine a significant influence using these models) and how can we extract the p-values used for these stars?

Answer (score 1):

A detailed description of the methods available in R to calculate p-values for the parameters estimated by `lmer` can be found typing `?lme4::pvalues`.
Below I show the code for calculating p-values for the Kenward-Roger-corrected tests:

```
library(lmerTest)
fm1 <- lmerTest::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
lmerTest::anova(fm1)

#############
Analysis of Variance Table of type III  with  Satterthwaite 
approximation for degrees of freedom
     Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F.value    Pr(>F)    
Days  30031   30031     1    17  45.853 3.264e-06 ***
```

The `stargazer` command in the `stargazer` package print p-values for estimated parameters:

```
library(stargazer)
fm2 <- lme4::lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
stargazer(fm2, type="text", report="vcp")

===============================================
                        Dependent variable:    
                    ---------------------------
                             Reaction          
-----------------------------------------------
Days                          10.467           
                             p = 0.000         

Constant                      251.405          
                             p = 0.000         

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    180            
Log Likelihood               -871.814          
Akaike Inf. Crit.            1,755.628         
Bayesian Inf. Crit.          1,774.786         
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question I am trying to understand the specific p-values that are being displayed by the screenreg function. Using the Satterthwaite approximation they appear to be similar to that derived from a t distribution but uncorrected. Is this correct? The code is essentially: model <- lmer(A ~ N+ T +  VxG  + TxG + NxG + NxV + TxN  + (T| id /Tr ), data = raw)
screenreg(list(model), single.row = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

In `texreg` p-values for `lme4` objects are calculated by the `extract.lmerMod` command. 
 See the following example:

```
library(lme4)
data(oats, package="MASS")
(fm1 <- lmer(Y ~ V*N + (1| B/V), data = oats))

##############
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['merModLmerTest']
Formula: Y ~ V * N + (1 | B/V)
   Data: oats
REML criterion at convergence: 529.0285
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 V:B      (Intercept) 10.30   
 B        (Intercept) 14.65   
 Residual             13.31   
Number of obs: 72, groups:  V:B, 18; B, 6
Fixed Effects:
        (Intercept)          VMarvellous             VVictory              N0.2cwt              N0.4cwt              N0.6cwt  
            80.0000               6.6667              -8.5000              18.5000              34.6667              44.8333  
VMarvellous:N0.2cwt     VVictory:N0.2cwt  VMarvellous:N0.4cwt     VVictory:N0.4cwt  VMarvellous:N0.6cwt     VVictory:N0.6cwt  
             3.3333              -0.3333              -4.1667               4.6667              -4.6667               2.1667
###############
```

Using `extract.lmerMod` we get:

```
extract.lmerMod(fm1)

###############
                         coef.      s.e.            p
(Intercept)         80.0000000  9.106977 1.570989e-18
VMarvellous          6.6666667  9.715025 4.925730e-01
VVictory            -8.5000000  9.715025 3.816101e-01
N0.2cwt             18.5000000  7.682954 1.604334e-02
N0.4cwt             34.6666667  7.682954 6.417271e-06
N0.6cwt             44.8333333  7.682954 5.365224e-09
VMarvellous:N0.2cwt  3.3333333 10.865337 7.590063e-01
VVictory:N0.2cwt    -0.3333333 10.865337 9.755259e-01
VMarvellous:N0.4cwt -4.1666667 10.865337 7.013620e-01
VVictory:N0.4cwt     4.6666667 10.865337 6.675591e-01
VMarvellous:N0.6cwt -4.6666667 10.865337 6.675591e-01
VVictory:N0.6cwt     2.1666667 10.865337 8.419413e-01

                           GOF dec. places
AIC                   559.0285        TRUE
BIC                   593.1785        TRUE
Log Likelihood       -264.5143        TRUE
Num. obs.              72.0000       FALSE
Num. groups: V:B       18.0000       FALSE
Num. groups: B          6.0000       FALSE
Var: V:B (Intercept)  106.0618        TRUE
Var: B (Intercept)    214.4771        TRUE
Var: Residual         177.0833        TRUE
```

Looking inside the `extract.lmerMod` function, the p-values are calculated as follows:

```
betas <- lme4::fixef(fm1)
Vcov <- vcov(fm1)
Vcov <- as.matrix(Vcov)
se <- sqrt(diag(Vcov))
zval <- betas/se
(pval <- 2 * pnorm(abs(zval), lower.tail = FALSE))

##################
        (Intercept)         VMarvellous            VVictory             N0.2cwt             N0.4cwt             N0.6cwt VMarvellous:N0.2cwt    VVictory:N0.2cwt 
       1.570989e-18        4.925730e-01        3.816101e-01        1.604334e-02        6.417271e-06        5.365224e-09        7.590063e-01        9.755259e-01 
VMarvellous:N0.4cwt    VVictory:N0.4cwt VMarvellous:N0.6cwt    VVictory:N0.6cwt 
       7.013620e-01        6.675591e-01        6.675591e-01        8.419413e-01
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this Marco, I apologize if my question was unclear on first pass

Comment: I did hit the up arrow, but because I am a novice user it says it will not display the upvote but will record it